# This code is working but after working Why this code is showing error

Tags: javascript

here is the html part ..

```js
var removeButton = document.getElementById("remove");
removeButton.addEventListener("click", removeItem);

function removeItem() {
  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  var listItems = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var last = listItems[listItems.length - 1];
  list.removeChild(last);

  if (last == listItems.length - 1) {
    document.getElementById("remove").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="abc">cold cereal</li>
  <li class="abc">Ice cream</li>
  <li class="abc">Honey</li>
  <li class="abc">Olive Oil</li>
</ul>
<button id="btn" onclick="myfun()">add item</button>
<button id="remove">remove item</button>
```

clicked on the remove button and its removing the items from the list after all the items are deleted from the list its showing the error .

[image]

when i run this code every thing is working fine but when all the items are deleted from the list after deleting all the list items from the list when i press the button once more it shows the error

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, but please remember to [put in the effort to write a good post](/help/how-to-ask) if you want to get good answers.

Comment: What do you think `listItems[listItems.length - 1]` will return when `listItems` is empty? Also, `last == listItems.length - 1` will **never** be `true` since `last` is not a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know why you used this

```js
if( last == listItem.length - 1)
{
document.getElementById('remove').disable = true;
}
```

try this

```js
if(listItem.length - 1 === 0){
        document.getElementById("remove").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this way

```js
const 
  removeButton = document.getElementById('remove') 
, list         = document.getElementById('list')
  ;
removeButton.addEventListener("click", removeItem);

function removeItem()
  {
  let
    listItems = list.querySelectorAll('li')
  , lastRef   = listItems.length - 1
    ;
  list.removeChild(listItems[lastRef] );

  if (lastRef === 0) {
    removeButton.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="abc">cold cereal</li>
  <li class="abc">Ice cream</li>
  <li class="abc">Honey</li>
  <li class="abc">Olive Oil</li>
</ul>
<button id="btn" onclick="myfun()">add item</button>
<button id="remove">remove last item</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**When your all nodes are deleted then you can't perform delete operation you will have to apply a condition to overcome this**

**Replace your removeItem function code with the given below-**

```js
function removeItem() {
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    var listItems = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    if (listItems.length > 0) {
      var last = listItems[listItems.length - 1];
      list.removeChild(last);
    }
    else{
      alert("can't delete")
    }
  }
```

Comment: I hope you are getting the point, if not let's discuss little bit more.

Comment: i got the point and the code is working

Comment: @fazal thank you for the feedback and one last thing I would say if you like the answer then you can accept & like it or both, this will be a reward as well as motivation for me.